# Using accessor for column name in model gives error of "Undefined App\ModelName::$column_name"

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have used an accessor to get the modified value for a column, and I haven't used $appends for that because the accesor name is according to column name. It gives me error of undefined property App\ModelName::$colimn_name

```
// In controller
ModelOther::select('column_name')where(condition)->get();

//In ModelName model
public function getColumnNameAttribute()
{
    return "Hello ".$this->column_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an accessor for the column using `column_name` itself doesn't require `$appends`, that is correct, but only mistake is you missed out a parameter in accessor function which contains the value for `column_name` which is passed by laravel. You need not to use `$this`.

```
//In ModelName model
public function getColumnNameAttribute($column_value)
{
    return "Hello ".$column_value;
}
```